# Does Super Mario World count as a programming language?

Tags: discussion

Some time ago, YouTube user [Sethbling](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8aG3LDTDwNR1UQhSn9uVrw) has injected code into Super Mario World, and I am planning to make a challenge about it (Making pong, to be exact).

But, I should know first if it counts as a programming language.

Does it count as a programming language? If it does, How would we score them?

*Note: It is (accidentally) Turing-complete.*

Comment: I'm not even sure I'd consider Super Mario the programming language here. It's really just a weird input method for processor instructions which are the actual language being used.

Comment: @Riker It didn't solve my question, but I'll set it as a dupe.